# Lua: calling __index function works then throws error

Tags: lua

I'm trying to write Lua bindings so that one can call arbitrary functions on a userdata. An MCV example I've been working on is below.

In summary: we have the C function `newarray` pushed to a table in the Lua globals so that one can create a new array object. Suppose that the array is a database record. I have two kinds of operation that I want to perform on it after generating it with `newarray` (for this bad example): accessing an element, and destroying the object.

Since I don't know how many elements there will be (in a real world example), I decide to make `__index` a function and use an if-statement to determine if the function was "destroy" or anything else (i.e. "give me this element"). If it was "destroy", delete the object; otherwise, return the requested element.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>

#define TEST_METATABLE "_test_mt"

typedef struct
{
    int* array;
} array_t;

int newArray(lua_State* L)
{
    assert(lua_gettop(L) == 0);
    array_t* array = lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(array_t));
    array->array = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        array->array[i] = i;

    /* Set metatable */

    lua_getfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, TEST_METATABLE);
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);

    return 1;
}

int indexFunc(lua_State* L)
{
    int argc = lua_gettop(L);
    array_t* array = luaL_checkudata(L, 1, TEST_METATABLE);
    const char* key = luaL_checkstring(L, 2);
    int ret = 0;

    if (!strcmp(key, "destroy"))
    {
        if (argc != 2)
        {
            lua_settop(L, 0);
            luaL_error(L, "Invalid arguments");
        }

        if (array->array)
        {
            free(array->array);
            array->array = NULL;
        }

        printf("Finished destroy\n");

        lua_settop(L, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        if (argc != 2)
        {
            lua_settop(L, 0);
            luaL_error(L, "Invalid arguments");
        }

        if (lua_tointeger(L, 2))
        {
            lua_pushinteger(L, array->array[lua_tointeger(L, 2)]);
        }
        else
        {
            lua_settop(L, 0);
            luaL_error(L, "Bad index supplied");
        }

        lua_remove(L, 2);
        lua_remove(L, 1);
        ret = 1;
    }

    return ret;
}

int luaopen_TestArray(lua_State* L)
{
    /* Set up metatable */

    lua_newtable(L);

    lua_pushliteral(L, "__index");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, indexFunc);
    lua_settable(L, -3);

    lua_setfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, TEST_METATABLE);

    /* Set up 'static' stuff */

    lua_newtable(L);

    lua_pushliteral(L, "newarray");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, newArray);
    lua_settable(L, -3);

    lua_setglobal(L, "TestArray");

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled with:

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -fPIC -shared -o TestArray.so test.c -llua
```

The Lua test program is as follows:

```
require("TestArray")

a = TestArray.newarray()

print(a[5])

a:destroy()
```

The output:

```
$ lua test.lua
5
Finished destroy
lua: test.lua:7: attempt to call method 'destroy' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        test.lua:7: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
$
```

So Lua does what it's supposed to by retrieving the 6th element's value (in terms of C) and printing it (as it surely does through `indexFunc`). Then it proceeds to execute the destroy-specific code in `indexFunc`, *then* tries to look for a function called `destroy`, and I have no idea why. It found the `__index` metamethod, so I don't understand why it looked elsewhere afterwards. Why does it do this, and what am I doing wrong?

Lua version: 5.1.4.

Comment: `__index` metamethod should only retrieve the value for the key "destroy", that is, `indexFunc` must only return a value (function "destroy") without executing this function.  Destructor should be implemented as separate function `int destroyFunc(lua_State* L)`.  Fast solution: just replace `a:destroy()` with `local _ = a.destroy` :-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Ohh, I see, so it's because of the parentheses after `destroy` which basically mean "invoke the result of retrieving 'destroy' as a function"? If you'd like to submit it as an answer I will accept, because AFAIK you don't get any well-deserved rep from a comment. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

__index is expected to return a value. Yours doesn't.

Specifically, when you write this:

```
a:destroy()
```

That is equivalent to:

```
getmetatable(a).__index(a, "destroy")(a)
```

i.e. call the __index metamethod, then call whatever it returns passing it `a` as the argument.

But if we look at your __index implementation, it doesn't respect that contract:

```
int indexFunc(lua_State* L)
{
  int argc = lua_gettop(L);
  array_t* array = luaL_checkudata(L, 1, TEST_METATABLE);
  const char* key = luaL_checkstring(L, 2);
  int ret = 0;

  if (!strcmp(key, "destroy"))
  {
    /* ... delete the array ... */
    lua_settop(L, 0);
  }
  else
  {
    /* ... push the value ... */
  }

  return ret; /* since key == "destroy", ret == 0 here */
}
```

If the key is `"destroy"`, it doesn't return a function; instead it destroys the array *immediately* and returns nothing, which is equivalent in this case to returning nil. Then the lua code tries to call the returned nil and explodes.

Instead, you need to create a *separate function* that does the destroy, e.g.

```
int destroyFunc(lua_State * L) {
  array_t array = luaL_checkudata(L, 1, TEST_METATABLE);
  free(array->array);
  array->array = NULL;
  return 0;
}
```

And then have your __index return that function rather than calling it:

```
lua_pushcfunction(L, destroyFunc);
return 1;
```

At which point the Lua code will be able to call that function.